# Why still getting JNA error on Cassandra startup, even the jna.jar and platform.jar are there in the lib dir?

Tags: cassandra, jna

I have downloaded and copied Jna.jar and Platform.jar to /usr/cassandra/apache-cassandra-1.0.7/lib folder, but still see the following error on Cassandra startup, am I missing anything?

```
"On cassandra JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled."
```

And the following are where I get the Jna.jar and Platform.jar

https://github.com/downloads/twall/jna/jna.jar
https://github.com/downloads/twall/jna/platform.jar

Comment: Check if this applies to you: http://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2010/11/11/enabling-jna-in-cassandra/

Comment: I'm experiencing problems using Cassandra with JNA enabled on Ubuntu -- process hangs, only solved by power cycle reboot...

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [suggested in comments post](http://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2010/11/11/enabling-jna-in-cassandra/).

Ubunto 12.10
Cassandra 1.1.6

I fixed this by

```
sudo apt-get install libjna-java
sudo ln -s /usr/share/java/jna.jar /usr/share/cassandra/lib
```

Comment: I removed the /usr/share/cassandra/jna.jar and make the symlink. Now: CLibrary.java (line 121) JNA mlockall successful. Thanks!