# How to solve jna not found issue in cassandra1.1.2

Tags: cassandra

I'm using cassandra 1.1.2 on ubuntu os.
I see the following log at start:

```
INFO 14:42:59,319 JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
```

I've found [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561189/why-still-getting-jna-error-on-cassandra-startup-even-the-jna-jar-and-platform), but I'm not sure about the versions and where should I locate this files.

Could someone describe the exact steps to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Do you have libjna-java installed?

Comment: Use dpkg -l libjna-java to check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why still getting JNA error on Cassandra startup, even the jna.jar and platform.jar are there in the lib dir?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561189/why-still-getting-jna-error-on-cassandra-startup-even-the-jna-jar-and-platform)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this :

```
$ ln -s /usr/share/java/jna.jar /usr/share/cassandra/lib
```

It will works ;) It'll turn to Jna mlockall ;)

Answer (score 1):

First install `lib-jna`:

```
sudo apt-get install libjna-java
```

Next, create a symbolic link in your cassandra lib directory (assuming `$CASSANDRA_HOME` is your installation directory):

```
ln -s /usr/share/java/jna.jar $CASSANDRA_HOME/lib/
```

The JNA log message on your Cassandra startup (`JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.`) should not be gone and Cassandra will use JNA.